# Adjunction on simplicial sets I

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

I am trying to understand the proof adjunction described in [page 244-245, of Joyals Theory of Quasicategories.](http://mat.uab.cat/~kock/crm/hocat/advanced-course/Quadern45-2.pdf)

> Background: $$i^*:S/I \rightarrow S/\partial I = S \times S$$
>
> - $S$ is category of simplicial sets.
> - $I$ is the simplicial set $1 \star 1$, where $1$ is terminal object $\star$ is join operation (explained also in the notes).  $\partial I= 1 \sqcup 1$.
> - $S/I$ is over category. Objects are $X \rightarrow I$, $X \in S$.
> - The construction is as follows, we given $X \rightarrow I$ in $S/I$, we $i^*X$, is the pullback of $X$ along inclusion $\partial I \rightarrow I$.

---

In proof Prop. 3.5, pg 245, the author assumes the existence of *right adjoint* $i_*$. How is this true?

Comment: The existence of the right adjoint in this case is purely formal and is obtained by taking the left Kan extension of the identity along the pullback functor.

Answer (score 2):

The category $S$ is **locally cartesian closed**, as is any presheaf category.

Indeed, for any $A\in S$, the category $S/A$ is equivalent to the category of presheaves over $\Delta/A$ (the category of elements of $A$). Any map $f:A\to B$ induces a functor $\Delta/f: \Delta / A \to \Delta / B$ and you can check that the restriction functor
$$ {-} \circ (\Delta/f) : \widehat{\Delta/B} \to \widehat{\Delta/A}$$ 
fits in a commutative square as follows:
$$\require{AMScd} 
\begin{CD}
\widehat{\Delta/B} @>{{-} \circ (\Delta/f)}>> \widehat{\Delta/A}
\\
@V\simeq VV @VV\simeq V 
\\
S/B @>>{f^\ast}> S/A
\end{CD}
$$
where the two verticals maps are the equivalence mentioned above. As the top map admits a right adjoint (the right Kan extension functor), so does the bottom map. All the constructions are *explicit*, so you can derive a formula for the right adjoint $f_\ast$ if needed.

Alternatively you can follow the recipe of showing that exponential object exist in $S$ (this is after all the special case of $B=1$ above) and adapt it to directly describe $f_\ast$.

Comment: Thanks a lot - but why does the right Kan extension exist?

Comment: @CL. A functor $F:\mathcal A \to \mathcal E$ admits a right Kan extension along $G: \mathcal A \to\mathcal B$ as soon as $\mathcal E$ is complete (because then the extension can be computed pointwise as limits). In our case, any presheaf $P: (\Delta/A)^{\rm op}\to \mathsf{Set}$ will then admit a right Kan extension along $(\Delta/f)^{\rm op}$, let us denote it $R_fP$. The mapping $P \mapsto R_fP$ can easily be promoted to a functor, which is the right adjoint you are looking for.